# Excel: Transformation / Rearrangement of Data

Tags: excel, transformation, data-manipulation

Gurus,

I have data provided as displayed in `A1:D19`.

Is there any clever way of transforming this data into the form as seen in `F3:I5` ?

If possible, I would like to rearrange the data without using VBA. Maybe a Pivot-Table can help (never worked with it so far)?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Pivot table or VBA sounds like the only options to me.

Comment: May be possible without VBA if you have Excel 2016, which contains the useful function `TEXTJOIN`. Even then it would be a challenge, probably not worth doing. In earlier versions of Excel, there's no good way (without VBA) to convert an array to a comma-separated list in a single cell. VBA is my recommended option.

Comment: Thank you guys. I started with a Pivot Table and I can transform it to the wished format just with Pivot and Excel-Functions. A bit of a hussle but looks like it works. Anyhow, thanks for your input!